# MagicalRecord -- saveinBackground not persisting data?

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I'm having trouble understanding the difference betweeen `[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] save]` and `[[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveInBackground]`.

When I use the `save` functionality, it works just fine but `saveInBackground` never persists the data. In short, this is the difference:

```
// Save in background.. DOES NOT WORK
    [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveInBackgroundErrorHandler:^(NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"FAILED TO SAVE!! Task: %@", task);
    }completion:^(void){
        NSLog(@"PERSISTED NEW TASK: %@", task);
    }];

    // Save in main thread.. WORKS
    [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] save];
```

Everytime `saveInBackground` runs, I see the "PERSISTED NEW TASK" log entry. However, when I restart the app, the data isn't there. When I use `save`, I restart the app and the data is there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to call `[context saveNestedContexts]`