# MagicalRecord context save not persisting data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I have an app which, on the first run, downloads a bunch of data from a backend service (StackMob but I don't think the choice of service is a factor here), caches it to plist files, & loads the data from the plists into a Core-Data store. On subsequent runs it uses the same classes to get any new or updated data & synchronise it into the Core-Data store. I'm using MagicalRecord instead of Apple's Core-Data stack & import/sync is performed in an NSOperationQueue.

That queue runs one method for each of 8 entities & one of those methods looks like this...

```
- (void)processAppData
{
    NSString *entityName = kEntityAppData;                                          // customise for entity
    NSString *smidName = kAttribute_appdata_id;                                     // customise for entity
    NSArray *syncData = [MFGlobals cachedDataForName:entityName];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[MFGlobals cachePathForDownloadNamed:entityName]
                                               error:nil];
    if (!syncData) return;

    NSLog(@"%@ items: %i", entityName, [syncData count]);
    NSNumber *lastUpdated = [MFGlobals lastUpdatedEntityNamed:entityName];
    NSLog(@"Last updated %@: %qu", entityName, [lastUpdated unsignedLongLongValue]);

    for (NSDictionary *item in syncData) {
        AppData *object;                                                            // customise for entity
        NSString *smid = [item objectForKey:smidName];
        NSNumber *lastmoddate = [item objectForKey:kAttribute_lastmoddate];
        NSLog(@"%@ item with ID: %@ lastmoddate: %qu", entityName, smid, [lastmoddate unsignedLongLongValue]);

        object = [self dataItemFromEntity:entityName withID:smid inField:smidName];

        if (!object) {
            // we have to create a new item
            object = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName
                                                   inManagedObjectContext:localContext];
            [object setAppdata_id:smid];                                            // customise for entity
        } else {
            // we have an item that _might_ need updating
            if ([object lastmoddate] >= lastmoddate)
                continue;
        }

        [object setLastmoddate:lastmoddate];
        [object setValue:[item objectForKey:kAttribute_value]];
        NSLog(@"new/updated %@ object: %@", entityName, [object description]);

        [localContext saveNestedContexts];
        NSLog(@"%@ object updated.", entityName);

        if ([lastmoddate compare:lastUpdated] == NSOrderedDescending)
            lastUpdated = lastmoddate;
    }

    [MFGlobals setLastUpdated:lastUpdated forEntityNamed:entityName];
    NSLog(@"New last updated %@: %qu", entityName, [lastUpdated unsignedLongLongValue]);
}
```

If I use `[localContext save]` instead of `[localContext saveNestedContexts]` the process appears to run correctly. The data appears in my UI when & how it should & I can navigate around in my app but the data doesn't persist to the sqlite database.

Taking a cue from here [MagicalRecord -- saveinBackground not persisting data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410213/magicalrecord-saveinbackground-not-persisting-data) I switched to using `[localContext saveNestedContexts]` & it now processes & persists the data for the first 6 entities correctly. However in the first record of the next entity it saves that record correctly & then my app enters a lock state. When I run the app again the same happens on the next (effectively the first new) record of that entity. When I have all the data in that entity the same happens with the first (& currently only) record of the next (& last entity).

The approach I've described here is essentially the same as I successfully used used with Apple style Core-Data code except that I'm using a MagicalRecord provided `NSManagedObjectContext` & MagicalRecord save methods on the context.

I did also try doing this using the MagicalRecord `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` (not using a queue) but ran into the locking on first record problem with all my entities.

Any clues as to how I can get this working properly?

Cheers & TIA, Pedro